# What type to make child object of reference data?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, business-objects

I have an Object `CaseNote` which has numerous child object's like `CaseNoteContactType`.  For 1 CaseNote there can be x CaseNoteContactType's.  In the UI ContactTypes are shown in a CheckListBox.

My question is how do I represent the ContactType child object?  It is a simple `int|string` pair.

```
public Class CaseNote
{
  public Guid CaseNoteID { get; set; }
  ...
  public ??? ContactType { get; set; }
  etc...
// Down here would be Methods for saving, loading, validating, etc...
}
```

Would `ContactType` be a `Dictionary`?  `IEnumerable<ContactType>`?  An `array`, `collection`, or `List<ContactType>`??

What makes sense in these scenarios?  A ContactType cannot exist with out a CaseNote but is it enough to make it an Object?  I don't understand the implications of each type.  Also, does it matter that a CaseNote can have 0 to 30 ContactTypes?

Say I do go the route of creating a ContactType class does a child class need a property for storing it's Parent's ID?

Guidance greatly appreciated.

If I am way off here it is because I have never really properly set up a Business Object and am now struggling to fit my environment into what I have read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ContactType sounds like reference data.  A CaseNote may have 0 or N ContactTypes, and a single ContactType may be assosciated with many CaseNotes.  Is that correct?

If so, I would suggest you make a new type called ContactType which contains two properties, Id and Name (assuming thats what the int and string are for):

```
public class ContactType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your CaseNote class, I would declare them as a List (or an IList interface):

```
public IList<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
```

To check if they have any ContactTypes you can do:

```
if( myCase.ContactTypes.Count > 0 )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe you've got the right of it.  tblCaseNoteContactType stores the CaseNoteID that they are associated with and an ItemID which is the ContactType with the description stored on a Maintenance Table.  Make sense...